# csh command not found always appear in the ubuntu terminal

Tags: shell, ubuntu, csh

I want to run a program using terminal under ubuntu. I installed the csh using the command:

`sudo apt-get install csh`

and it is successfully installed, the output was:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
csh is already the newest version (20110502-2.1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 230 not upgraded.
```

and when I write the following commands, it wasn't working:

```
shaimaa@ubuntu:~/MT_inv/bin$ #!/bin/csh -f
shaimaa@ubuntu:~/MT_inv/bin$ sudo MT_inversion.csh SS SS TEST
sudo: MT_inversion.csh: command not found
```

How can I run the program or make the terminal defin/find the command?

Comment: try `sudo ./MT_inversion.csh SS SS TEST` the `#!/bin/csh -f` will do nothing, if you want to switch into it just type `csh`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no thing happens and i can't run the program

Comment: Try this.  From your regular shell, type `csh`.  The `echo $SHELL`.  This should print csh.  Just to make sure.  Then try your sudo.  Sudo might not find the script anymore, you might have to cd into the proper directory, or call `sudo /full/path/MT_inversion.csh ...`

Comment: many thanks for your answer. but i did as you said and it is still give me the same error as follows:% csh
% echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
% cd MT_inv
% cd bin
% ls
mt_convert      mt_greenM        mt_inversionM1     mt_obsdata
MT_get_WAVE.OBS.csh  MT_inversion.csh  MT_inversion_MM.csh  mt_sac2asc.csh
% sudo MT_inversion.csh
[sudo] password for shaimaa: 
sudo: MT_inversion.csh: command not found
% sudo /full/path/MT_inversion.csh
sudo: /full/path/MT_inversion.csh: command not found